# React Native how to make an action when a user first puts their finger on a screen and then (without lifting it) goes over a pressable which activates

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo, touch-event, pressable

I am building a React Native app and I am trying to make it so that when a user can slide their finger from a place not on the pressable to the pressable without lifting their finger and when the finger is over the pressable an action happens. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `onHoverIn` prop on the `Pressable` see the [React Native Pressable docs](https://reactnative.dev/docs/pressable#onhoverin)

```js
<Pressable onHoverIn={() => console.log("entered me")}>
  <Text>Enter me</Text>
</Pressable>
```

See here a [Snack Expo preview](https://snack.expo.dev/xTD4fcfsv)

Comment: it only works on web. on ios nothing is happening.